# Use of subprocess with Linux pipe command

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run from Python script next command:

```
strings <FILE NAME> | grep "Version = <VERSION STRING>" > /dev/null
```

I need to save command return code and command output for following script logic.

Currently I used next code:

```
     strings_out = subprocess.Popen(('strings', file), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     grep_output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', "Version = " + version_string), stdin=strings_out.stdout)
     strings_out.wait()
```

I get error

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('grep', 'Version = <VERSION STRING>')' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

My assumption is that *check_output* run out of memory.

What is wrong in my use of subprocess?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, it just isn't finding any matches.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Just check whether a match exists or not? (You don't really need grep for this, you can easily check the output of `strings` directly in Python.)

Comment: I Hope you need to mention `strings_out.wait()` after the first line of above code. Chances are there that the `grep` command ran without the completion of the first command, for instance if the output of `strings` command is large.

Comment: @alaniwi, what do you mean saying _check the output of strings directly in Python_?

Comment: @BaruchLi You can read the output of `strings` into python and use python regular expressions (or even just `in` for simple substring search) to test whether the version string you are looking for is present.

Comment: @alaniwi, what should be reasonable limit for size of `strings` command out I can storage in Python varible?

Comment: @BaruchLi That just depends on your available memory - there is no limit as such. But you don't have to read all the `strings` output in at the same time: you could still loop over lines in the way that `grep` would do (`for line in strings_out.stdout:` etc)

Answer (score 0):

A non-zero exit status for a check_output means that the bash command had a problem - I don't think you ran out of memory.

On testing myself, I found that if I gave grep a string that exists within a file, I got a proper output with your code (I'm not using Version because I don't know what input files you have, but otherwise things are just about the same).  I do, however, get the same error you get if I grep a string that doesn't exist.

Maybe you are running it on a file that string doesn't output any instances of `"Version = " + version_string`.  If you are in a loop, it would only take one file to not have the proper string to get the error.

On another note, if you plan on finishing this line: `strings <FILE NAME> | grep "Version = <VERSION STRING>" > /dev/null` with subprocess, you'll be piping the output to /dev/null.  In this case, you won't see the output of grep.

Answer (score 0):

As @samsonjm has mentioned, every successfully ran bash command has the `exit code = 0`. It implies that the `grep` command has failed. Moreover, there is no clue for an OutofMemory error.

I suspect that input file to the `strings` command is large and hence it could be taking more time to return its result. Therefore, I suspect the `string_out.wait()` directive should be called immediately after the first line above to feed in the input from `stdin` to the `grep` command. It is reasonable to think in this way as the subprocess executes commands in a child process that might be running until completion.

```
strings_out = subprocess.Popen(('strings', file), stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
strings_out.wait()
grep_output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', "Version = " + version_string), stdin=strings_out.stdout)
```

Comment: This code stuck in 'strings_out.wait()'. I am still not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

That's neat, I've never thought to use subprocess stdin/stdout like that before. However, my advice would be to either go pure Python and write a method to search for the string in a file, or get a little fancier with your subprocess line.

Python might look something like:

```
import os
search_term = bytes("Version = " + version_string, encoding='utf-8')
i = 0
found = False
file_size = os.stat(f).st_size
chunk_size = len(search_term) *10
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
    while f.tell() < size:
        x = f.read() #read a small amount of data
        i += chunk_size - len(search_term) #to make sure we don't miss the search_term
        f.seek(i)
        if search_term in x:
            found = True
            break
```

For subprocess:

```
cmd = f'strings {file_name} | grep "Version = {version_string}"'
test = subprocess.run([cmd], shell=True, capture_output=True)
test.returncode
```